# Load page using two URLs

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i was just wondering if i could call two URLs at the same time in AJAX.you see i'm loading two pages using jquery at the same time and i'm planning to use a pagination made up of jQuery too.the only solution i could see is to create several pages for this to be possible.

this is my first page to be loaded.this calls the different php scripts depending on the chosen option from the drop box.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/themes/gray.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#view").change(function(event)
    {
        var view=$(this).val();
        switch(view)
        {
            case "daily":
            {
                $("#graph").load('pagination.php');
                break;
            }
            case "weekly": 
            {
                $("#graph").load('weekly_graph.php');
                break;
            }
            case "monthly":
            {
                $("#graph").load('monthly_graph.php');
                break;
            }
            case "yearly":
            {
                $("#graph").load('yearly_graph.php');
                break;
            }
            default: 
            {
            }
        }
    }); 
});
      </script>
     </head>

     <body>

     <div align="center">
       <select id="view">
        <option>(Choose which view...)</option>
            <option value="daily" >Daily</option>
            <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
            <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
            <option value="yearly">Yearly</option>
       </select>
    </div>
  <br/>
       <div id="graph"><?php include ('pagination.php');?></div>
```

example i have chosen monthly view there will be two pages to be included then two more drop downs could be seen.from the drop downs another 2 more pages will be called upon choosing from the options.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
       {
          $("#months").change(function(event)
           {
              var m=$(this).val();
              if(m!='00' || m!='NULL')
               {
                   $("#memcount").load('month.php', {"m":m, "y": $("#years").val()});
         $("#top10").load('top10_monthly.php', {"m":m, "y": $("#years").val()});
      }
  });

  $("#years").change(function(event)
   {
      var y=$(this).val();
      if(y!='10' || y!='NULL')
      {
          $("#memcount").load('month.php', {"y":y, "m": $("#months").val()});
          $("#top10").load('top10_monthly.php', {"y":y, "m": $("#months").val()});
      }
   });

});
     </script>  

     <div>
         <select id="months">
            <option value='00'>Month...</option>
                    <option value='01'>Jan</option>
                    <option value='02'>Feb</option>
                    <option value='03'>Mar</option>
                    <option value='04'>Apr</option>
                    <option value='05'>May</option>
                    <option value='06'>June</option>
                    <option value='07'>July</option>
                    <option value='08'>Aug</option>
                    <option value='09'>Sept</option>
                    <option value='10'>Oct</option>
                    <option value='11'>Nov</option>
                    <option value='12'>Dec</option>
                  </select>
                 <select id="years">
                              <?php
                               for($yr=10; $yr<=$year; $yr++)
                      {
                                         echo "<option value='".$yr."'>".$years[$yr]."</option>";
                      }
                    ?>
                      </select>
                    </div>
               <div id ="memcount"><?php include('curr_month.php')?></div>
               <div id="top10"><?php include('curr_top10m.php')?></div>
```

each page to be loaded i have to place a jquery pagination.could somebody please help me with this? :(

sample pagination

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE admin_level LIKE 'CRD' ORDER BY id LIMIT       $start, $per_page";
        $result =mysql_query($sql);
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Taipei');
        $today = date('m');
        $b=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
         $name[$b] = $row['first_name'];
         $id[$b]= $row['id'];
         $b++;
         } 
        for($i=0; $i< $b; $i++)
     {
    $aug_id = mysql_query("SELECT count(crdid) AS augtotal FROM crd_project 
                                WHERE crdid!='NULL' 
                                    AND timestamp LIKE '%/$today/%' 
                                    AND crdid='$id[$i]'");
      while($aug_num= mysql_fetch_array($aug_id))
      {
          $aug_tot[] = (int)$aug_num['augtotal']; 
      }
} 



      /* --------------------------------------------- */
      $query_pag_num = "SELECT count(*) AS count FROM tbl_user WHERE admin_level LIKE 'CRD'";
      $result_pag_num = mysql_query($query_pag_num);
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
      $count = $row['count'];
      $no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

                   /* ---------------Calculating the starting and endign values for the          loop----------------------------------- */
              if ($cur_page >= 7) 
                {
               $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
              if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
                 { 
         $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
        }
        else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6)   
       {
              $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
               $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
            }
          else 
     {    
         $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    }
 }
                else 
                {
                  $start_loop = 1;
                 if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
                {
              $end_loop = 7;
            }
                else
          {
                   $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
          }
        }


                  $msg .= "<div class='pagination'><ul>";


               // FOR ENABLING THE PREVIOUS BUTTON
                if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) 
              {
            $pre = $cur_page - 1;
            $msg .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Previous</li>";
          }
      else if ($previous_btn) 
         {
        $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
          }

     // TO ENABLE THE NEXT BUTTON
      if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations)
      {
          $nex = $cur_page + 1;
          $msg .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Next</li>";
      } 
      else if ($next_btn)
       {
         $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
           }


       $total_string = "<span class='total' a='$no_of_paginations'>Page <b>" .    $cur_page . "</b> of <b>$no_of_paginations</b></span>";
      $msg = $msg. "</ul>".$goto . $total_string . "</div>";  // Content for pagination
      echo $msg;

      $data = json_encode($aug_tot); 
      $fname = json_encode($name);
      $number = json_encode($b);

       }
      ?>
          <div id='memcount' style='width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto'></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'memcount',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Daily Count of Added Clients',
                    x: -10 //center
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories:<?php echo $fname;?>
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Number of Clients'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'left',
                },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Total',
                            data: <?php echo $data;?>
                        }]
                    });
                });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax you can not call two pages at the same time.

You could create a helper page on the server side which combines the two pages your trying to retrieve now.

Comment: No. You can actually make 2 AJAX calls at the same time.

Comment: How is that, if you mean same time as two ajax requests happening simultaneously, then yes. But you cant call a server and ask for two pages at the same time, what would the header response be.

Comment: You could create a page called combined_pages.php or whatever you want to name it. In that page call what ever your functions or code is say pageOneFunction and pageTwoFunction and add the return into a named array json_encode('pageOne'=>$pageOneReturn,'pageTwo'=>$pageTwoReturn);

Comment: shobe, is the the second piece of code you posted both your pages you call from ajax?

Comment: yes.i could call both of the pages.they are displaying on the memcount and top10 div